# Why I am getting blank screen while using v-for in my Laravel page with vue js

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I am getting a blank screen while using v-for on my Laravel page with vue js
When I am trying to loop through with this I am getting the blank screen I tried in totally new test project without Laravel then its working fine Thanks in advance I have attached my code below.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="_app">
                <div class="panel-heading">View Folder</div>

                    <button type="button">add item</button>
                      <button type="button">change first item</button>

                      <ul>
                        <li v-for="vl in list">[[vl.name]]</li>

                      </ul>




            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




@endsection
```

and the vue js code is:

```
Vue.options.delimiters = ['[[', ']]'];
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#_app',
    data: {
    list: [
      {name: 'first', label: 1},
      {name: 'second', label: 2},
      {name: 'third', label: 3}
    ],
    idx: 4


  },
  methods: {
    // addItem: function() {
   //    this.list.push({name: 'new item', label: this.idx++})
   //  },
   //  removeItem: function(item) {
   //   this.list.$remove(item)
   //  },
   //  changeFirst: function() {
   //   this.list[0] && (this.list[0].name = this.list[0].name.toUpperCase())
   //  }
  }
})
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer: this code is running in vue.js displayng the list (and doing nothing else: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faina09/hoo2o6mc/)); Laravel can introduce some issue, but it depends from your environment

Comment: Yes , Actually when I am using template property then its working absolutely fine

Answer (score 0):

The data you provided are insufficent to answer, anyway I assume you used a standard Laravel+vue.js boiler plate (versions?), and should check the following:

- are "npm (or yarn) install" runned with no warnings/errors?
- is "npm run dev" reporting any error?

I noticed that you have a lot of new lines and a wrong alignment in your source, if you use a lint be sure to respect its rule (normally you cannot have more than one white line, you must end your code with a newline, ...)